# Error when opening my dialog inside another component Angular

Tags: java, html, typescript, module, angular5

I have a configuration module of my system, when I access the configuration page I have several components inside the configuration component.

I am trying to open a MatDialog inside the component that is inside the component configurations.

Below is the tree of my files and the @NgModule of configurations.

> settings
>
> > mysettings1
> >
> > > > dialogs
> > > >
> > > > > dialog1.component.ts
> > > > >
> > > > > dialog1.component.html
> > > > >
> > > > > ....
> > > >
> > > > forms
> > > >
> > > > > form1.component.ts
> > > > >
> > > > > form1.component.html
> > > >
> > > > mysettings1.component.ts
> > > >
> > > > mysettings1.component.html
> >
> > settings.module.ts

Within `settings.module.ts` I added in Dialog1 `declarations`, also added in Dialog1 `entryComponents`.

I have `Form1` component inside the `MySettings1` component and I am trying to run the `Dialog1` component from the `Form1` component.

The following error occurs when trying to open `Dialog1`:

```
ERROR Error: No component factory found for Dialog1Component. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?
    at noComponentFactoryError (core.js:3925)
    at CodegenComponentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory (core.js:3989)
    at CdkPortalOutlet.attachComponentPortal (portal.es5.js:655)
    at MatDialogContainer.attachComponentPortal (dialog.es5.js:190)
    at MatDialog._attachDialogContent (dialog.es5.js:864)
    at MatDialog.open (dialog.es5.js:720)
    at Form1Component.addForm (form-1.component.ts:37)
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (Form1Component.html:25)
    at handleEvent (core.js:13547)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:15056)
```

Even though I'm importing into declarations and entryComponents the error is occurring, I think this has to do with the directory where my Dialog1 is located.

For elsewhere in my system I can open all Dialogs normally without problem.

The only difference now is the directory where the components are located.

**app.module.ts**

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'settings',
        loadChildren: './main/content/pages/settings/mysettings.module#MySettingsModule',
    },
    {
        path: 'auth',
        loadChildren: './main/content/pages/authentication/authentication.module#AuthenticationModule',
    },
    {
        path: '**',
        redirectTo: 'dashboard'
    }
];

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        // FIREBASE
        AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
        AngularFireAuthModule,
        AngularFirestoreModule.enablePersistence(),
        AngularFireDatabaseModule,

        BrowserModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
        TranslateModule.forRoot(),

        DashboardModule,
    ],
    bootstrap: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        AuthGuardService,
        AuthService
    ]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Comment: Can you post your `app.module`?

Comment: Posted app.module, check please.